# I get bus errors when using fread(), and bad data when using buffered stream buffer

Tags: c, solaris, fread

```
FILE * fh = fopen(fname, "rb");
setvbuf(fh, bf, _IOFBF, KB64);
int n = fread(bf, 1, KB64, FH);

/* DISPLAY first 50 characters*/

fclose(fh);

fh = fopen(fname, "rb");
setvbuf(fh, bf, _IONBF, KB64);
int n = fread(bf, 1, KB64, FH);

/* DISPLAY first 50 characters*/

fclose(fh);
```

The above code gives me completely different data. the _IONBF gives me the correct data, but the app takes much more time than the _IOFBF code. Using Apex C++ on solaris. Simply using setbuf() gives me a bus error when program is called multiple times. Not specifying buffer, also gives me bus errors when program called multiple time. I have no clue why I would get a bus error to begin with, and then bad data when buffer is "buffered".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically, the issue is that when I used the setvbuf to assign a buffer for the OS to use internally, and then used fread() to read from a file into the same buffer, I ended up not getting the exact content of the file I was reading. It seems that one should not use the stream assigned by setvbuf() for any data manipulation.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution to the above problem. Correct code follows.
Data read is fast and accurate :).

```
FILE * fh = fopen(fname, "rb");
char bf[KB64], fhistream[KB64]
setvbuf(fh, fhistream, _IOFBF, KB64);
int n = fread(bf, 1, KB64, FH);
```

Comment: Please explain why your code in the question was not working and how your answer fixes that. You may add links to the documentation wherever needed.

Comment: I don't know the answer to either question. I assume that setvbuf assigns a buffer for the OS to use internally when executing the fread procedure, and copying the buffered data from it to itself may not be a good thing!